# Why isometry between $l_p^n$ and $l_q^n$ carries 0 to 0

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

I'm reading [the paper by Felix Cabello Sanchez and Jesus M.F. Castillo](http://matematicas.unex.es/%7Efcabello/files/printable/01.pdf) to prove a theorem:

> Denote $(\mathbb{R^n, ||\space||_p})$  as $l_p^n$. Then $\forall p, q \in [1, \infty]$, if $p \neq q$, then there's no isometry between $l_p^n$ and $l_q^n$.

From the paper's pp2, it said "It is enough to consider the case of linear isometries". This seems to based on the fact that, if there's an isometry $f$ between $l_p^n$ and $l_q^n$, then $f(\mathbf{0}) = \mathbf{0}$.

According to the definition of isometry in wiki, a bijective function $f: X \to Y$ is an isometry if $\forall a,b \in X, d_X(a,b) = d_Y(f(a), f(b))$. I failed to prove why $f: l_p^n \to l_q^n$ has to map $\mathbf{0}$ to  $\mathbf{0}$.

Thank you!

Comment: A translation is an isometry @rubikscube09

Comment: @rubikscube09: If one is only considering them as metrics spaces, not vector spaces, then an isometry need only preserve distances, not norms. Consider a self-translation, as nicomezi has made reference to.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Yes exactly, my confusion is that how can we deduce from distance (not norm) preservation to 0 -> 0.

Comment: IsaKyodo: Are you familiar with the concept of "without loss of generality (WOLOG)"? They're not saying it has to map $0$ to $0$, they are saying WOLOG you can assume it does. ...

Comment: ...  I.e. if you use the hint provided by @nicomezi, you can say that "If there is an isometry (that may not map $0$ to $0$), then you can compose it with an appropriate translation and get an isometry that does", and then go on and (probably) prove that leads to a contradiction. (BTW, I don't know how they get linearity from mapping $0$ to $0$, but that's not what you asked about.)